# Ajax problems when loading into a div. Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not so good on javascript, and I am trying to load some images into a div, via an external html page, with some opacity function in jquery. Is there a simple function that will re apply the scripts needed once the ajax call has been made. I have seen jquery live, but before I start tearing my hair out, I wondered if I was on the right tracks. Or is there a really simple method I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) are your friends.

Specifically, you should try to use `delegate`, because events bound with `live` bubble up all the way up the DOM before they're caught.

The syntax for `delegate` is:

```
$("#parent_element").delegate(
    "#child_selector_event_occurs_on", 
    "click" // <-- Event to declare a handler for
    function() { ... });
```

The linked documentation page for `delegate` has some examples.

**Edit:**

My answer above assumes that you're losing event handlers that are bound to content that's being replaced or updated with AJAX.  If you need to do things like re-initialize widgets or run other custom code, you'd benefit by moving that code into a common function and calling it upon a successful load of new content (and in your `document.ready` handler).

For example:

```
function init() {
    /* Write initialization code here */
}

$(document).ready(function() { init(); });

/* Later on, when you reload the content: */
$("#ajaxified").load("foo.html", function() { init(); });
```

Another alternative is the [`livequery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin, which I haven't used but I've heard good things about. Specifically, you'd be looking at the helper function functionality:

```
$('#selector') 
    .livequery(function(){ 
        /* Write code here to execute when a new element matching the 
           selector is added. */
        init();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still struggling with this. Would I change the following code. function LoadNewContent(id,file){
 $("#"+id+" .customScrollBox .content").load(file,function(){
  mCustomScrollbars();
 });
}

Comment: @simon: You should edit your question if you have a more specific issue. `delegate` and `live` will only work on event handlers. If you need to reinitialize a widget or run other code, you'll have to do that every time you load the AJAX content.

Comment: Sorry Andrew. What you just said was what I meant. I just was not sure on how to phrase it. How do I re initialize or re run the code. Is there a simple way.

Comment: @simon: I expanded my answer with some possible routes you could take.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am looking at them now. I was looking at live query a little while ago. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @simon: Cool! Hope you find it useful, please keep me posted.

Comment: @simon: Did this end up helping you at all?